# Excel - column to row

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following list of data:

```
A1
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

and I need to transform the data to:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 
1   2  3  4  5

A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
 6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Is this your real data or is your real data much bigger? Do you need to do it just once or regularly? There are multiple solutions, all are different compromise between complexity and manual data manipulation, we need to know above details to suggest the one best fitting for your situation.

Comment: @MátéJuhász my real data is a list of 8000 codes which I need once to split in 8 columns so I have a result of 1000 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In A1 enter formula:
`=INDEX($J$1:$J$8000,(ROW()-1)*8+COLUMN())`

Copy the formula to all cells of A1:H1

In the address bar type "A1:H8000", then press CTRL+D to fill the formula to all rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA code. Please do not forget to update *sourceRange*, *targetCell* and *columns* values.

```
Sub GenerateMatrix()
Dim rows As Integer, columns As Integer
Dim sourceRange As Range
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim cellCount As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim arr As Variant
Set sourceRange = Range("Sheet2!A1:A10")
Set targetCell = Range("Sheet2!A1")
cellCount = sourceRange.Count
ReDim arr(1 To cellCount)
For i = 1 To cellCount
    arr(i) = sourceRange.Cells(i, 1)
Next i
columns = 5
rows = cellCount / 5
For j = 1 To rows
    For i = 1 To columns
        targetCell.Offset(j - 1, i - 1) = arr((j - 1) * columns + i)
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```