# Excel - How do I distribute rows to 5 columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I copied data from a 5 column web table that unfortunately gave me only a "line-break"-separated list. Pasting in Excel gives 1 column with many rows, where a set of 5 rows represents 1 row (with 5 columns) from the original table.

How do I restore the original 5 rows?
e.g. data

```
A1
B1
C1
D1
E1
A2
B2
C2
...
```

to

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1
A2 B2 C2 D2 E2
...
```

I know of the transpose command, but that doesn't apply here.
I also found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1326516/excel-column-to-row), but I don't see how I could apply the answers to my question, since my request is a bit different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I would like to suggest two possible methods, one in using Formula and another is VBA Macro.*

[image]

**Method 1:**

- Formula in cell X1:

  ```
  =IF(INDEX($V:$V,ROW(V1)*5-5+COLUMN(A1))=0,"",INDEX($V:$V,ROW(V1)*5-5+COLUMN(A1)))
  ```

---

**Method 2:**

- To get the VB editor either press **Alt+F11** or right click the sheet TAB and from pop up menu hit VIEW CODE.
- Copy & Paste this code as Standard Module.
- Press **Alt+Q** to return to the sheet & Save the file as Macro Enable *.xlsm.
- RUN the Macro.
- While responding first INPUT BOX select V1:V11 and for second INPUT BOX select X7.

  ```
   Public Sub TransposeData()

   Dim xLRow As Long
   Dim xNRow As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim xUpdate As Boolean
   Dim xRg As Range
   Dim xOutRg As Range
   Dim xTxt As String
   On Error Resume Next

   xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address

   Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Select data range(only one column):", "Transpose", xTxt, , , , , 8)
   Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)

   If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   If (xRg.Columns.Count > 1) Or _
      (xRg.Areas.Count > 1) Then
       MsgBox "the used range only contains one column", , "Transpose"
       Exit Sub
   End If

   Set xOutRg = Application.InputBox("Select output range(specify one cell):", "Transpose", xTxt, , , , , 8)

   If xOutRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

   Set xOutRg = xOutRg.Range(1)

   xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   xLRow = xRg.Rows.Count

   For i = 1 To xLRow Step 5
       xRg.Cells(i).Resize(5).Copy
       xOutRg.Offset(xNRow, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
       xNRow = xNRow + 1
   Next
   Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate

   End Sub
  ```

**N.B.**

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Glad to help you @Honeybear ,,, keep asking ☺